# JQuery: Autocomplete selection event is not triggered

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm (pretty) new to JQuery, but have been reading page after page on the autocomplete feature. I cannot get the select event to trigger when selecting an item from the drop-down list.

This is the code:

```
    $("#newTag").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax",
                datatype: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {searchText: request.term},
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.tag,
                            id: item.id
                        };
                    }));
                },
                select: function(event,ui) {
                    alert("Selected ");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

It returns the right data from the ajax call, so that seems to work fine. I have made an example searching through an array, which worked fine. But I cannot seem to find the error in the above code.

All help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select property is on the ajax call not the autocomplete

```
$("#newTag").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax",
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {searchText: request.term},
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.tag,
                        id: item.id
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event,ui) {
        alert("Selected ");
    }
});
```